# Data model for family members

Tags: database, data-modeling, graph-databases, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-clustering

I am not a database expert., However I have a business case in which I want to store information related to a large family with more than 20,000 members , starting from a patriarch and inserting new members who are born , the data concern their names , dates of birth , occupations , data of death and so on.

What is the best data model for such case ?

After making a research I am a little bit confused between hierarchal or graph data model , So , does any of them fit the problem or another solution is better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem fits perfectly within the realm of graph databases and is fairly easy to implement. In InfiniteGraph, the data model would look something like the following:

```
    UPDATE SCHEMA {
    CREATE CLASS Person {
        name        : String,
        dateOfBirth : DateTime,
        dateOfDeath : DateTime,
        education   : List { 
                        Element: Reference { EdgeClass: Education, EdgeAttribute School },
                                 CollectionTypeName: TreeListOfReference
                        },
        residence   : List { 
                        Element: Reference { EdgeClass: Residence, EdgeAttribute Address },
                                 CollectionTypeName: TreeListOfReference
                        },
        birthMother     : Reference { referenced: Person },
        birthFather     : Reference { referenced: Person }
    }
    
    
    CREATE CLASS Education {
        startDate   : Date,
        endDate     : Date,
        certificate : String,
        
        school      : Reference { Referenced: School }
    }
    
    CREATE CLASS School {
        name        : String
    }
    
    CREATE CLASS Residence {
        startDate   : Date,
        endDate     : Date,
        
        address     : Reference { Referenced: Address },
        resident    : Reference { Referenced: Person }
    }
    
    CREATE CLASS GeoPosition {
        latitude    : Float,
        latitude    : Float
    }
        
    
    CREATE CLASS Address SUPERCLASS GeoPosition {
        street1     : String,
        street2     : String,
        city        : String,
        state       : String,
        country     : String,
        postalCode  : String,
        
        resident    : List { 
                        Element: Reference { EdgeClass: Residence, EdgeAttribute Person },
                                 CollectionTypeName: TreeListOfReference
                        }
}
}
```

InfiniteGraph is a massively scalable object-oriented graph database. I've solved many problems like yours using the product.